# SoundCloud Javascript API SC.get() not pulling through all tracks

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I have been using javascript soundcloud GET API [SC.get(url)] to fetch sound tracks of a particular soundcloud url but somehow this url (https://soundcloud.com/user-811076785/sets/week-1) is returning me only 7 records out of 13 total records. Any reasons why instead of returning 13 records its returning me only 7.

```
$ curl "http://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/238899952?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
```

This above command returns you 7 tracks under Tracks array in the returned JSON but there are total 13 tracks on url (https://soundcloud.com/user-811076785/sets/week-1).

Also for getting the id(238899952) used in above curl hit, is obtained as follows :

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.1.2.js"></script>
<script>
SC.initialize({
    client_id: 'CLIENT_ID'
}); 

SC.resolve("https://soundcloud.com/user-811076785/sets/week-1")
.then(function (type) {
    id = type.id   // this is the id
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: I don't know about SC API, but maybe it uses pagination? https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#activities - Pagination subsection.

Comment: I have tried giving limit to 15 for pagination and even removing limit so that all tracks can be fetched but its not returning all tracks. Is it possible that those not returned sound tracks have some kind of flag/permission which is not allowing the api to read/fetch them ?

Comment: I have added example using curl hit for fetching tracks as well.